# nginx 301 redirect with query string

Tags: redirect, nginx

Currently I have something like this in my nginx.conf file:

```
location ~ /old/page/?$ {
    return 301 /new-page;
}
```

The issue is that query strings are being stripped from the /old/page?ref=xx URL.

Is it possible to include query strings using the redirect method I'm using above?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Anything from the `?` and after is the query string and is not part of the normalised URI used in `location` and `rewrite` directives. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) for details.

If you want to keep the query string, either add it to the `return`:

```
location = /old/page/ {
    return 301 /new/page$is_args$args;
}
```

Or with `rewrite`, the query string is automatically appended unless a `?` is added:

```
rewrite ^/old/page/$ /new/page permanent;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for location syntax, and [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) for return/rewrite.